# HTML5 + JS load content dynamically from JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, html

I'm about to do single static website with informations about how to do different types of bandages. I decided to use Bootstrap+Boilerplate combination (served by initializr) and now I'm having following problem:

- for each bandage type (about 30 of them) I will have it's name, short description, type of bandage, link to video and also long description (probably in HTML formating with headings)
- since website must be able to run online and also offline from e.g. USB disk, it is not possible to use PHP, Python etc. nor even database.
- I don't want to create same website for every bandage type (it would be tedious to mantain and to much of duplicated code), so I decided to save these informations as entries in JSON file (think about it as a database) and then I'd like to create pages for bandages "dynamically" from this JSON file.

example: I have link on my page:

```
<a href="http://www.bdtypes.com/bandages/head_crit.html">Head critical bandage</a>
```

Now I'd like to open some template page with informations (header, subtitles, content, videolink...) loaded from JSON file with key "head_crit".

Is this even possible? Or are there any better approaches? I know that jQuery is able to load JSON file, but I'm not familiar with it's possibilities and even if this solution is good or stupid...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is a good option regarding to what you want to do.

You can use jQuery to load json files easily: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).
You can also create it directly inside your javascript but it is not very conventional.

What you can do is to load a json file containing all the information at the first launch and then store it into session such as.

```
var yourJson = {
    headCrit: {
        name: "blabla"
        link: "blabla"
    },
    headOther: {...}
};
```

*(when you store JSON in session you will have to use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify)*

Then you can change you data with:

```
function changeHeader (header){
     $("#ElementForName").text( yourJson[header].name );
     ....
}
```

Loading json files are asynchronous therefore it can take time depending on how big is you data and you might need to create a loading effect meanwhile your data is loading

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm kind of novice to JS, so could you please give me an example where to place that code?

Comment: Nevermind - I've figured it out. I will paste solution with example based on this idea. Thank you :)